# R Shiny downloadHelper multiple write.csv + file.copy

Tags: r, download, shiny

I am using Shiny to produce a data.frame which the users can download by clicking on a button:

**server.R**

```
output$downloadresults <- downloadHandler(
    filename= function() {
      paste(country, " - Provision report.csv", sep = "")
    },
    content=function(file) {
      write.csv(sheet1_report,file)
    }
  )
```

When the user clicks the download button, I (simultaneously) want to copy a second file from my server to the same location to where they are downloading the data.frame.

**Importantly, I am trying to avoid a secondary button.**

So the idea is to add the line `file.copy("C:/temp/asdf.csv", file)`:

```
output$downloadresults <- downloadHandler(
    filename= function() {
      paste("User_chosen_filename", sep = "")
    },
    content=function(file) {
      write.csv(sheet1_report,file)
      file.copy("C:/temp/asdf.csv", file) #NEW LINE
    }
  )
```

This is not working, R only executes the first `write.csv` line and ignores the `file.copy`.

I have tested the `file.copy` in isolation and it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd love to have an answer to this one as well. If you figure it out please post.